# How to enable GRASS plugin in QGIS 1.8.0 (Linux Mint 13 - 64 bit)?

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, qgis-plugins

Every time I enable GRASS plugin in QGIS (Plugins -> Manage Plugins -> GRASS), I got a message: Exception - G_getenv(): Variable GISDBASE not set.
I googled and found some information [here](http://osgeo-org.1560.n6.nabble.com/Reset-GISDBASE-for-GRASS-plugin-td4128428.html) but don't know how to "unset GISRC".
Anyone please show me how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it. I don't know if every step below is necessary but here's what I've done:

- Open the terminal and run GRASS from it.
- Create new Location and Mapset
- Import some data, save and quit.

Now I can open QGIS and enable GRASS plugin with no problem.

Comment: If you could mark your answer as solved that would help other users as well

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to unset `GISRC`

In order to do so:
Go to Computer>System Properties>Advanced System Settings>Advanced>Environment Variables >>> delete the `GISRC` variable

Comment: Your answer is for Windows systems while my question is about Linux. May be it will be of help to those who use Windows. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Sorrry I didn't read carefully and missed that it is about Linux. But I guess Windows user have the same problem...